# How can I make an entity invulnerable to fall damage?

Tags: minecraft-modding, entity

I've been using minecraft forge 1.12 to make a mod that gives the user super-jumping abilities. However, I've been having trouble making the player invincible to fall damage. I've tried to use a `LivingFallEvent` like this:

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void onEntityFall(LivingFallEvent event) 
{
    event.setDistance(0.0F);
    event.setCanceled(true);
}
```

but the player still gets damage from falling. What did I do wrong?

If you need it, here is my full code:

```
package com.blockmaster6678.totalweirdmod;

    import java.util.List;

import com.blockmaster6678.totalweirdmod.init.ModBlocks;
import com.blockmaster6678.totalweirdmod.init.ModItems;
import com.blockmaster6678.totalweirdmod.money.MoneyWorth;
import com.blockmaster6678.totalweirdmod.money.PlayerMoney;
import com.blockmaster6678.totalweirdmod.proxy.CommonProxy;
import com.blockmaster6678.totalweirdmod.util.Attributes;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityPlayerSP;
import net.minecraft.command.CommandBase;
import net.minecraft.command.CommandException;
import net.minecraft.command.ICommand;
import net.minecraft.command.ICommandSender;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityItem;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityCow;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.init.Enchantments;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.init.MobEffects;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketPlayer.Position;
import net.minecraft.potion.PotionEffect;
import net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living.LivingDropsEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living.LivingFallEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.world.BlockEvent.HarvestDropsEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;

@Mod(modid = Attributes.ID, name = Attributes.NAME, version = Attributes.VERSION)
public class Main {
    private static boolean helped = false;

    @Instance
    public static Main instance;

    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Attributes.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Attributes.COMMON_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @EventHandler
    public static void PreInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new Object() {
            @SubscribeEvent
            public void yourPlayerHarvestEvent(HarvestDropsEvent event) {
                if (event.getHarvester() != null) {
                    if (event.getState() == ModBlocks.IVY_BLOCK.getDefaultState()) {
                        event.setDropChance(0.99F);
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Item.getItemFromBlock(ModBlocks.IVY_BLOCK), 20));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.FIREWORKS, 32));
                    } else if (event.getState() == Blocks.DIRT.getDefaultState()) {
                        event.setDropChance(1.0F);
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Item.getItemFromBlock(Blocks.DIRT), 64));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Item.getItemFromBlock(Blocks.CHORUS_FLOWER), 1));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Item.getItemFromBlock(Blocks.CACTUS), 2));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Item.getItemFromBlock(Blocks.SAND), 16));
                    } else if (event.getState() == Blocks.CACTUS.getDefaultState()) {
                        event.setDropChance(0.5F);
                        event.getDrops().clear();
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Item.getItemFromBlock(Blocks.CACTUS), 2));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.BLAZE_ROD, 5));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.EXPERIENCE_BOTTLE, 64));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.BAKED_POTATO, 12));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.DIAMOND_SWORD, 1));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.APPLE, 49));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.ENDER_PEARL, 16));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.MAGMA_CREAM, 23));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.ELYTRA, 1));

                        Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.
                                    addItemStackToInventory(new ItemStack(Item.getItemFromBlock(Blocks.CACTUS), 1));
                    } else if (event.getState() == Blocks.SAND.getDefaultState()) {
                        event.setDropChance(0.1F);
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Items.ELYTRA, 1));
                        event.getDrops().add(new ItemStack(Item.getItemFromBlock(ModBlocks.IVY_BLOCK)));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @EventHandler
    public static void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {

    }
    @EventHandler
    public static void Postinit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {

    }
    @EventHandler
    public static void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        EntityPlayer p = event.getEntityPlayer();
        World world = p.getEntityWorld();
        BlockPos pos = event.getPos();
        if (!(p.getHeldItemMainhand().getItem().equals(Item.getItemFromBlock(ModBlocks.IVY_BLOCK)))) {
            return;
        }
        world.setBlockState(new BlockPos(pos.getX() + 1, pos.getY(), pos.getX()), ModBlocks.IVY_BLOCK.getDefaultState());
    }
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onEntityFall(LivingFallEvent event) {
        event.setDistance(0.0F);
        event.setCanceled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onEntityFall` method is not registered to the event bus. Notice where your `yourPlayerHarvestEvent` method is and how its context differs from `onEntityFall`.

Additionally, you should use a complete class, rather than a runtime generated object, for your event handlers. This class can also be static (with static methods) and registered with annotations. See [the docs](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events/intro/#static-event-handlers)

```
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber
public class MyStaticForgeEventHandler {
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void arrowNocked(ArrowNockEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Arrow nocked!");
    }
}
```

Your `onPlayerInteract` is also not being called. Both because of the incorrect context already mentioned, and because it has the incorrect annotation `@EventHandler` which is only for Forge lifetime events (preInit, etc).